# Mixing Partial KeyPaths and Arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, keypaths

Apologies if this is trivial, but I have not yet gotten my head around KeyPaths fully.  I have a class (ContainerClass) which has an array of classes in it (mySettings). the mySettings Class has two variables (color and name).  The array of mySettings is defined at runtime.  I am trying to modify the properties in the mySettings class via KeyPaths.  The following code is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation


class Settings {

    var color: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(color: Int, name: String)    {

        self.color = color
        self.name = name
    }
}

class ContainerClass    {

    var mySettings = [Settings]()
}


var myClass = ContainerClass()

let kp = \ContainerClass.mySettings
let kp2 = [\Settings.color, \Settings.name]

myClass.mySettings.append(Settings(color: 1, name: "One"))
myClass.mySettings.append(Settings(color: 2, name: "Two"))
myClass.mySettings.append(Settings(color: 3, name: "Three"))
myClass.mySettings.append(Settings(color: 4, name: "Four"))
myClass.mySettings.append(Settings(color: 5, name: "Five"))


for index in 0..<myClass.mySettings.count   {
    print(myClass.mySettings[index].color!)
}

let target = myClass[keyPath: kp][0][keyPath: kp2[0]]

print("\ntarget:", target as! Int)

myClass[keyPath: kp][0][keyPath: kp2[0]] = 128      // ERROR: Cannot assign through subscript: 'myClass' is immutable

for index in 0..<myClass.mySettings.count   {
    print(myClass.mySettings[index].color!)
}
```

I need two separate KeyPaths: one to target one specific mySettings element of the array contained in ContainerClass, and another KeyPath to target one of the two properties within the Settings class.  At runtime, the program will determine which element of the array and which property must be modified.

I can read the property (in my example via: let target = myClass[keyPath: kp][0][keyPath: kp2[0]]), but I cannot modify it by trying, for example, a line like: myClass[keyPath: kp][0][keyPath: kp2[0]] = 128.  I get an error: Cannot assign through subscript: 'myClass' is immutable.

I am not sure about the interaction of these partial keypaths with arrays.  Any help on how to resolve this (i.e. being able to modify properties within Settings this way) will be much appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the key paths in the second array have different types. How should the compiler verify that you can assign an integer to `myClass[keyPath: kp][0][keyPath: kp2[0]]` ?

Comment: Thank you Martin.  I think I understand the problem.  I am not quite an expert on Swift but If you could help me in finding a way around this I would appreciate.  Thanks again